# CSS Styling interupted by Table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I haven't been able to figure out this issue. It is my first foray into z-index and I am trying to apply a left hand shaded box and can't get it to go under the table. check out the jsfiddle link, the box uses the following css, but will not go to the top left. I tried playing with the z-index of the other things and putting them at different values. If I put the box at 1 instead of -1 it will go to the right place, but I can't bring the menu sub items and the logo above it.

http://jsfiddle.net/GTKn9/

```
.leftbox
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    height: 100%; 
    width:  220px; 
    background-color: #36454f; 
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: is that what you want: http://jsbin.com/cuhanuxa/1/edit ?

Comment: @aldanux Yes that is exactly it. But why did the div need to surround the table when I used absolute positioning? I understood that it released it from it's position and "floated" to wherever it was told to go and would be under / over whatever else was there.

Comment: Grrr, now the `<div>` is causing the table that previously went across the screen to be constrained to the width of the div.

Comment: how else do you want your table position? Your `div leftbox` was `empty` so that is useless... Well, I would glad to help you but I'd have to know what you want to achieve?

Comment: @aldanux Later in the HTML in one of the table cells I have `<div class="contentarea"></div>` which is a placeholder to populate things via jquery. So the table was supposed to go across the entire screen, the first cell had the navigation, the second the content. But this way I can't expand the content area without enlarging the leftbox div.

Comment: can you make a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) with your jquery code?... Put your `div contentarea` outside from them?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to visualize what you are trying to achieve. However, I think you may have more success if you change your markup. Tables really should only be used for tabular data and not for layout. Also, float was intended for use with positioning images, not other elements. In most all cases you should be able to avoid using float. 
To get position:absolute to work a little easier, try setting the elements parent container to position relative. That way the child element will be positioned relative to the parent. (confusing?)

I have created [a basic layout](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/pCsFc) for you. Again im not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but perhaps this will be a good starting point?